# Update all images on Google Bookmark Manager

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I really enjoy bookmarks, so I use [Google Bookmark Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik?hl=en).  However, I found out about it only recently, so some of my bookmarks don't have pictures attached yet:

[image: Google Bookmark Manager]

Is there any way to update the pictures on all of the websites?  I have hundreds and hundreds of bookmarks and would rather not have to do it manually.

Comment: What you have here is the new bookmark manager for Chrome which [wasn’t that popular with users](https://medium.com/@d4nyll/why-the-new-chrome-bookmarks-sucks-ce4b33cf1931). After months of silence, [Google has quietly confirmed](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/mhIX5LB23As) that it’s ripping out this new bookmark manager and rolling back to the old one. Using this software, you would in effect be using depreciated software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: First ***Export*** your Bookmarks to HTML File (to have a backup before).
Step 2: Uncheck "**Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed**" option from *Settings*.
Step 3: Close '*Chrome*' (make sure there is no "**chrome.exe**" process is running from *Task Manager*).
Step 4: Now browse to "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" ([user data directory](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)) and *rename* "**Favicons**" to "**Favicons.bak**" and "**Favicons-journal**" to "**Favicons-journal.bak**" (*This step may lead to no icons of bookmarked pages, to restore rename files back to original name*).
Step 5: Re-open *Chrome*.

**Remarks:**

*(i)* Try Clearing browsing data & *Cache* (make sure to clear **Cookies**, **Cache** and **Hosted App Data**) after *Step 2*.

*(ii)* Try using "**Open all bookmarks in new window**" option from *Bookmark Manager* to force chrome to *re-download* all icons after *Step 5*. (This will suck your *RAM*)

*(iii)* If the above method does not work, you can try using *[Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh)* extension.

*(iv)* Last but not least, you can try "**Open all bookmarks in new window**" option and "**Bookmark open pages**" option to *re-bookmark* all the open pages (Again this will suck your *RAM*).

**Done!**